# Getting the size of a Multidimensional Array

Tags: java

Im currently stuck trying to get the size of the elements. It works if it in 2d

```
          String[][] = new String[5][10];  

          System.out.println(test[1].length);
```

However lets say i have this

```
          String[][][] = new String[5][10][15];
          System.out.println(test[2].length);
```

The above would not work. Is there anyway to get the size of the 3rd element which is 15?
Edited. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Why you say "The above would not work" What is the exception you get then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your example is a 3D array, you want the length of the "second dimension":

```
System.out.println(test2[0][0].length);
```

Answer (score 3):

each multidimensional array is simple an array where each element contain an array.

so in case of 3 dimensional  array each element has 2 dimensional array inside. and each element of it has 1 dimensional array inside. So you need to do:

```
 String[][][] array = new String[5][10][15];
 int length = array[0][0].length;
```

So saying test[2] like in your code we are referring the 2 dimensional array which is on the third position and has a size [10][15]

Answer (score 2):

I imagine you would need something like `test[0][0].length`

Comment: `new String[5][10][15]` guarantees that arrays are created at each level. It just does not create the `String`s themselves at the very bottom level.

Comment: @Code-Guru That is what second sentence implying, No? At least I understood such a way :)

Comment: @Code-Guru I think I understand what you mean ;)

Comment: I was saying that you can make a stronger claim than *assuming*. We *know* that the array(s) at each level are created.